# Installing Angular Universal app in Cpanel

Tags: node.js, cpanel, angular-universal

I have an Angular Universal app that I've created. I need to install it on our dedicated cloud server running CentOS7, WHM and cPanel. I have access to everything.

I'm really struggling to find a decent resource to teach me how to do this. Here's what I've got so far.

I've managed to follow this tutorial successfully: https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/

I've got this basic single js file working in a subfolder of my domain and it displays correctly when i visit the address. One interesting thing is, for some reason, I had to put the `nodejsapp` folder in 2 different places; one in the root of the domain and again in `public_html`. If I rename either of them it suddenly stops working.

There's also some differences with my built angular app.

Firstly there's 2 folders, `server` and `browser`, secondly there isn't an `app.js` created as default, the closest I can see is `main.js` in the `server` folder. Is that what I'm looking for? I did (foolishly) try changing that to `app.js` but obviously that didn't work. I've set the application path to /dist/app/server.

I'm currently getting a `503 Service Unavailable`.

I know if you change it from app.js to main.js then I possibly need to do something with a `httpd` file but my knowledge stops there.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only a client app ( browser ), then you can simply "ng build" and upload the files from the "dist" directly to the public_html directory if you would like to be able to access them through your primary domain name. And create a .htaccess file with:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, it seems that you have both - a server and a client app. You can still apply the above for the exported files of the client, but you will have to run the server as well. It would be best to reach your web host for further help on that one.